# VBA Generating and modifying links

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have a Excel form which has 4 steps launched by links instead of buttons (I try to avoid them), these are 'Clear', 'Generate', 'Calculate' and 'Publish PDF'.

I call those links through:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink) 
If Target.Range.Address = "$L$13" Then
'Function
```

And so on. Where "$L$13" is the cell address where the first link is placed. Every link calls for its own cell address. Right now the code for this is a 'if...else if' loop for 4 premises (one per step).

'Clear' function is clear (this joke was on me).

'Generate' function copies and pastes a range of cells (the 'form') as many times as groups are indicated by the user. They are separated the same amount of rows.

'Calculate' function performs some hand calculations according user's inputs.

'Publish PDF' take the spreadsheet and print it in PDF.

Well, I have been requested to have a 'Calculate' button (and also a 'publish PDF' but it doesn't matter now) for each generated 'form' to push users to calculate results once per group.

Because it is a link, I can copy and paste the link with the rest of the form but I only got it to send the user to the original 'Calculate' button at the beginning of the sheet. The copied link keeps the subaddress of the original link (i.e. subaddress=L13)

Is there any chance to keep using links for calling each step but having many 'Calculate' links to the same function?

Thank you in advance.

I leave it the main structure of the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

'Comparing this with $L$13:$L$16

If Target.Range.Address = "$L$13" Then

'Clear button function                

Exit Sub

ElseIf Target.Range.Address = "$L$14" Then

'Generate button function

    'Copying_the_template (k)

        'This is an fail attempt to modify the link once it is pasted.

        'Cells(Group_index + 5, 10).Select
        'Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Address = Sheet3.Cells _
        (Group_index + 5,10).Address
        'ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add , SubAddress:=Sheet3. _
        Cells(Group_index + 5, 10)

ElseIf Target.Range.Address = "$L$15" Then

'Calculate button function

   Exit Sub

ElseIf Target.Range.Address = "$L$16" Then

'Publish PDF button function

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You couldn't do something like this instead - based on the cell's value?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    If Target.Range.Column = 12 Then    'is column L
        With Target.Range
            Select Case .Value
                Case "Clear"
                    'Clear button function
                Case "Generate"
                    'Generate button function
                Case "Calculate"
                    'Calculate button function
                Case "Publish"
                    'Publish PDF button function
            End Select
            Exit Sub
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you tell me if this is quicker/better than an usual 'if then' instructions? If so, I am going to start to start using it more often.

Comment: Don't know about quicker, the difference if any would be small I imagine, but I reckon it's easier to read/debug.